# If an Android service is killed, are threads spawned by the service killed as well?

Tags: android, multithreading, service

Suppose I implement a service that starts threads performing long-running operations.
If the service gets killed, will that automatically kill off those running threads as well?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Perroloco - Makes sense. I guess the "kill unit" is always the process level, thus taking down any threads as well.

Comment: @Cumbayah I'm not too sure about that "If an activity is paused or stopped, the system can drop it from memory either by asking it to finish (calling its finish() method), or simply killing its process". It doesn't seem it's always the process level. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A service runs in the same process as your app unless you specify otherwise in the manifest.  If it's killed (i.e., crashes) then all threads belonging to the process will disappear, but I don't think that's what you're asking.  Threads started by the service will not be terminated automatically if the service is stopped in the normal way, *unless* the service is running in another process *and* the process is also terminated.  It may not be.  Android tends to keep processes around even after the Activity or Service that was running in them has been stopped and destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this to also be true.
I wanted a thread in a background service (Main UI process). I wanted the service to be killed when the main activity was killed, however I found that my threads would keep on running even when the activity and service (stopSelf) had stopped/been stopped.

I had to explicitly kill the thread. I did this by calling yourThread.interrupt().